# JSON to Groovy parser

Tags: json, groovy

I found many things about converting Groovy to JSON, but oddly enough, not the other way.

What is the (best) JSON to Groovy parser around there ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because compiled Groovy classes are compatible with Java classes, you should be able to use any Java library for converting JSON to POJOs (or POGOs). [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) is a fairly popular choice which you can use to convert JSON like this:

```
String json = '{
  "name" : { "first" : "Joe", "last" : "Sixpack" },
  "gender" : "MALE",
  "verified" : false,
  "userImage" : "Rm9vYmFyIQ=="
}'
```

to a Map using:

```
Map<String,Object> userData = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class)
```

Or if you want to convert the JSON to a Groovy User class:

```
User userData = mapper.readValue(json, User.class)
```

This will map properties in the Groovy class to keys in the JSON.

In the code above, `mapper` is an instance of `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` from the Jackson library.

Comment: what is `mapper`?

Comment: @Gank `mapper` is an instance of `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` from the Jackson library

Answer (score 36):

If you are on Groovy 1.8 or later, there is a build in JsonSlurper you can use this way:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

//Attention: you have to use double quotes inside the json string
def jsonObj = new JsonSlurper().parseText( '{ "name":"Peter", "age": 23}' )

assert jsonObj.name == "Peter"
assert jsonObj.age == 23
//this won't work, because it's not defined
assert jsonObj.gender == null
```

Comment: JSONSlurper actually causes StackOverflow exceptions on some JSON documents due to liberal use of regexps and caveats in Java regexp implementation. See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4903 (marked as fixed but problem is still present)

Comment: JsonSlurper also doesn't deserialize dates from JSON, which is really annoying.

Comment: @erturne that may have something to do with Date not being part of the JSON standard. If the JSON you're getting has `new Date()` or other non-standand syntax, you will need to subclass JsonSlurper, otherwise you can just iterate over and fix the returned map.

Answer (score 6):

[JSON-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/groovy.html) claims to be able to transform POGO to JSON and back. If POGO means what I think it does (Plain Old Groovy Object), you're set :).

They give this example:

```
def strAsJsonObject = "{integer:1, bool: true}" as JSONObject
```

**Update**:

I've tried the lib myself, this is the complete code:

```
import net.sf.*;
import net.sf.json.*;
import net.sf.json.groovy.*;

println "hi"
GJson.enhanceClasses()
def strAsJsonObject = "{integer:1, bool: true}" as JSONObject
println strAsJsonObject
```

It'll chase you through a marathon of downloading dependencies (ezmorph, commons lang, commons logger) and once you've resolved them all, this is what you get:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException:
>   Cannot cast object '{integer:1, bool:
>   true}' with class 'java.lang.String'
>   to class 'net.sf.json.JSONObject'

According to [The mailing list](http://old.nabble.com/Groovy-JSON-integration-td16662688.html), you get this for not calling GJsonlib.enhanceClasses(), but I did call that, as you can see above.

I've concluded that it's a worthwhile endeavor to hate Groovy's JSON-lib.

Comment: That produces a cast error. I understood that what the `obj as JSONObject` syntax actually converts a Groovy object to JSON.

Comment: I then saw it on the doc, so this should work as intended, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Have you run GJson.enhanceClasses()?

Answer (score 4):

I use JSON-lib in [HTTPBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/), but I use the JSONSlurper class to parse a string to a JSON instance:

```
JSON jsonMapObject = new JsonSlurper().parse( "{integer:1, bool: true}" );
```

To go from Object to JSON, I do this:

```
//from a map:
new JSONObject().putAll( [one:'1', two:'two']).toString()
//from an object:
JSONObject.fromObject( somePOGO ).toString()
```

Comment: At this time, you need to use "new JsonSlurper().parseText" instead of using "new JsonSlurper().parse"

Answer (score 3):

To the people having trouble with json-lib and GJson.enhanceClasses(). Try GJson.enhanceString() instead.

```
GJson.enhanceString()
def o = "{\"x\": 20.0}" as JSONObject
```