# Converter from Json into groovy CODE?

Tags: java, json, groovy, converters

It's a kind of odd question for an odd situation. I have a large JSON structure which I would like to represent in running groovy code. I need groovy objects that mirror the same structure as the JSON objects.

As to be expected a web search mostly returns results with groovy/json runtime conversion stuff, but nothing about things that output groovy code.

You might think this lazy but really it is a massive JSON structure! A converter would save days!

Comment: You can use an instance of a groovy json object just like a plain groovy object. Or you want the object to be typed?

Comment: can you restate "Of course search queries only fill up with normal groovy json object at runtime conversion stuff."?  Having trouble parsing that sentence.

Comment: @Will P Yes ideally I would want typed groovy code

Comment: @Brian I clarified the question, hope that's better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Groovy's own `JsonSlurper` to parse JSON objects:

```
import groovy.json.*

def json = '{"name":"john", "surname":"doe", "languages": ["groovy", "python"]}'

def obj = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

assert obj.name == "john"
assert obj.surname == "doe"

assert obj.languages.containsAll("python", "groovy")
```

Of course the class is untyped: it's only known at runtime. If you want it to be typed, you can write a code which *writes the code* based on an example (since a [json schema](http://json-schema.org/) may be rare).

**EDIT**: if you want to generate the model classes code, you can try [JSONGen](http://jsongen.byingtondesign.com/), which "parses JSON to create client side source files to model the JSON data structure". I'm not aware of a solution for Groovy, but since java-groovy integrations is seamless, it shall work fine.

Comment: Excellent that looks like the solution, can't wait to try it out!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a Groovy representation of your JSON, you can get that via the built-in [JsonSlurper](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html).  This will give you Java Maps and Lists of data you can work with.

You can populate more specific, custom objects you've written to represent your JSON entities using the (3rd party) Jackson's [data binding functionality](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884979/json-to-groovy-parser) as well).

Answer (score -3):

Try using a JSON parser like [this one](http://flori.github.com/json/). According to its documentation you just need to do

```
JSON.parse
```

to deserialize the data